# Erlang matchspecs with tuple comparison

Tags: erlang, tuples, matching

I want to use `erlang datetime` values in the standard format `{{Y,M,D},{H,Min,Sec}}` in a `MNESIA table` for logging purposes and be able to select log entries by comparing with constant start and end time tuples.

It seems that the matchspec guard compiler somehow confuses tuple values with guard sub-expressions. Evaluating `ets:match_spec_compile(MatchSpec)` fails for

```
MatchSpec = [
{
{'_','$1','$2'}
,
[
{'==','$2',{1,2}}
]
,
['$_']
}
]
```

but succeeds when I compare `$2` with any non-tuple value.

Is there a restriction that match guards cannot compare tuple values?

Comment: How is your data stored in Mnesia? What does the record look like?

Comment: The problem is solved, thanks. I now can use values like erlang:now() or calendar:local_time() as record fields and filter on them. Did not read the matchspecs docs carefully enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is to use double braces when using tuples (see Variables and Literals section of http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/match_spec.html#id69408). So to use a tuple in a matchspec expression, surround that tuple with braces, as in,

```
{'==','$2',{{1,2}}}
```

So, if I understand your example correctly, you would have

```
22> M=[{{'_','$1','$2'},[{'==','$2',{{1,2}}}],['$_']}].
[{{'_','$1','$2'},[{'==','$2',{{1,2}}}],['$_']}]

23> ets:match_spec_run([{1,1,{1,2}}],ets:match_spec_compile(M)).
[{1,1,{1,2}}]

24> ets:match_spec_run([{1,1,{2,2}}],ets:match_spec_compile(M)).
[]
```

**EDIT**: (sorry to edit your answer but this was the easiest way to get my comment in a readable form)
Yes, this is how it must be done. An easier way to get the match-spec is to use the (pseudo) function `ets:fun2ms/1` which takes a *literal* fun as an argument and returns the match-spec. So

```
10> ets:fun2ms(fun ({A,B,C}=X) when C == {1,2} -> X end).
[{{'$1','$2','$3'},[{'==','$3',{{1,2}}}],['$_']}]
```

The shell recognises `ets:fun2ms/1`. For more information see [ETS documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html). Mnesia uses the same match-specs as ETS.